# Comparing phone numbers sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 sets of phone numbers in 2 different tables, `table 1` has the straight forward format of `01234567890` and the other table has 3 different formats, sometimes it's `01234567890` or `01234 567890` or `01234-567890`.

Currently I'm just doing an Inner join on the tables and only get a few rows returned but would expect more as obviously anything with a hyphen or space will get missed from the join.

The way the system is I can't change the data in the table with 3 formats so can't standardise it or clean it out etc.

What would be the best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you could think about creating a computed column in your second table to *normalize* the phone number format - something like:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourSecondTable
ADD NormalizedPhone AS REPLACE(REPLACE(PhoneColumn, '-', ''), ' ', '') PERSISTED
```

This expression removes any spaces and any dashes from the `PhoneColumn` and those values are stored in a new, computed column called `NormalizedPhone`.

This column will always be kept up to date - even if you change your `PhoneColumn`'s value later on. It will always contain the *normalized* phone number *automagically*.

Now you can easily join the two tables on the *normalized* phone strings, and you should get more accurate results.

Comment: Or, if you can't alter the table, create a view and join against that.  If you make it a persisted view, it should be just as fast

Comment: you could also think about replacing `+` with `00` for international numbers

Comment: @ninesided: absolutely - one could dream up a **lot more** things to filter out - this is just a sample based on the original question.

Comment: Could I on the join just do INNER JOIN PhoneNos b ON REPLACE(REPLACE(PhoneColumn, '-', ''), ' ', '') = b.PhoneNo ? I think that would work

Comment: @user1505127: you maybe could - but it's a bad idea - it *destroys* the efficiency of the JOIN; I'd recommend using this computed column and join on that instead