# Compare phone numbers of multiple formats in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to begin by saying that this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655813/comparing-phone-numbers-sql) sort of helps but my issues is a bit different.

I have two tables. The first one has:

```
| AREACODE| PHONENUMBER |  Company Name   |
===========================================
|   800   |   115-4454  | Sample Company  | 
|   800   |   141-2254  | Sample Company2 |
|   800   |   113-9857  | Sample Company3 |
```

The second table has:

```
|PHONENUMBER|
=============
|18001154454|
|  7274313  |
```

This formatting in the second table makes it really hard for me as someone not great in SQL to match the items across tables.

The difference in my question compared to the linked on is I can't alter the tables in any way.

The full requirement is that when a area code + phone number in table 1 match with the phone number in table 2, I need to select a column called company name.

I considered a solution using CASE WHEN to check the lengths and do complicated substring modifications but I doubt it would be the proper method. Any help would be appreciated. If I am unclear on anything please ask and I will do my best to clarify for you.

**EDIT**

All columns are strings.

The expected results would be the company name of any matches between the tables for the phone number and the phone number in it's original format from the first table (area code + phonenumber)

So from the above example I would expect

```
  PHONENUMBER   |  Company Name   |
===================================
  800-115-4454  | Sample Company  |
```

Comment: Can you please show some expected output samples

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: What datatypes are the columns?

Comment: @AaronD what datatype make this easier?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza If they are strings, he can use `AreaCode` + `PhoneNumber` to combine.

Comment: Where is the column `company name` and in your sample there isnt any match, is it?

Comment: Apologizes for not responding soon. The columns are all strings. @JuanCarlosOropeza the company name column is in table 1.

Comment: @TheGameiswar edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these are all string columns, you can get rid of the `-` with `REPLACE` and combine the separate columns to compare with the single column:

```
SELECT     CompanyName
FROM       SingleColumnTable S
INNER JOIN MultiColumnTable M on M.AreaCode + REPLACE(M.PhoneNumber,'-','') = S.PhoneNumber
```

In the case where there is a leading one:

```
INNER JOIN MultiColumnTable M 
   ON M.AreaCode + REPLACE(M.PhoneNumber,'-','') = S.PhoneNumber
   OR '1' + M.AreaCode + REPLACE(M.PhoneNumber,'-','') = S.PhoneNumber
```

In the case there is no area code:

```
INNER JOIN MultiColumnTable M 
   ON M.AreaCode + REPLACE(M.PhoneNumber,'-','') = S.PhoneNumber
   OR '1' + M.AreaCode + REPLACE(M.PhoneNumber,'-','') = S.PhoneNumber
   OR REPLACE(M.PhoneNumber,'-','') = S.PhoneNumber
```

Full Query:

```
SELECT     M.AreaCode + '-' + M.PhoneNumber "PhoneNumber", M.CompanyName
FROM       SingleColumnTable S
INNER JOIN MultiColumnTable M 
   ON M.AreaCode + REPLACE(M.PhoneNumber,'-','') = S.PhoneNumber
   OR '1' + M.AreaCode + REPLACE(M.PhoneNumber,'-','') = S.PhoneNumber
   OR REPLACE(M.PhoneNumber,'-','') = S.PhoneNumber
```

Disclaimer: This will probably perform like absolute trash and hopefully is not something you will need to use repeatedly.

Comment: This should work assuming all of the area codes matched in both tables. However, based on the question, it appears SingleColumnTable may have a one in front, or may have no area code at all

Comment: @JacobMorris Yeah, without more sample data it is hard to say.  I think this is the logic OP will want, but there could be plenty of other factors such as the leading 1 in area codes, or `NULL`s, and so on, that would require handling.

Comment: The problem is the leading 1 or the area code missing. I apologize for the minimal data. Thought it would give an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script.. I think there is a chance of empty spaces before and after the comparing strings..Also needs to expect null value in area code.

```
SELECT *
FROM SingleColumnTable S
 INNER JOIN MultiColumnTable M 
    ON LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(M.AreaCode,''))) + LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(M.PhoneNumber,'-',''))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(S.PhoneNumber))
```